Is Adding Hard Bounces to Auto-Suppression List a Good Practice in SFMC?
SFMC’s bounce management system marks subscribers as Undeliverable after:

1 bounce for trusted domains (e.g., Gmail, Hotmail).
3 bounces within 15 days for non-trusted domains.

For non-trusted domains, the system waits for 3 bounces in 15 days, which means emails might still be sent to problematic addresses in the meantime. I’m considering adding hard bounces directly to an Auto-Suppression List because:

Why wait for 3 bounces? If a hard bounce occurs, it’s unlikely the address will ever recover or become Active again.
This approach would protect sender/IP reputation by avoiding retries on invalid addresses.
It ensures a cleaner subscriber list and minimizes risks.
Does it make sense to proactively add hard bounces to suppression, or is relying on SFMC’s bounce management system sufficient?


I'd say "depends" on your business scenario.
Assuming you are a B2b-heavy customer (= few "trusted domains" in your pool), and your sendout pattern is monthly (=no 3 sendouts in 3 weeks => no 3 bounces in 3 weeks) - you will not see any hard bounces removed almost ever, they fall through that net.
If you are also interested in clean lists / want to actually remove hard bounces to work with realistic potentials in your distribution lists, an auto-suppression will help.
==
If you are a B2c volume sender, you will probably send enough to create sufficient data points for the built-in bounce handling. Then I also think the approach might be overengineering.
On the "how":
From my experience, support don't change the bounce settings on request anymore, meaning you need to work with an auto suppression list in case you want to do something.

I run B2C campaigns and have noticed that many subscribers in my database simply have invalid email addresses (e.g., typos, non-existent domains, etc.). That’s why I don’t see the point in waiting for three hard bounces for the system to mark such addresses as undeliverable. If I add them to the Auto Suppression List earlier, I can save my sender reputation by avoiding two additional sends that would result in hard bounces anyway. Do you think it is a bad approach?

The same applies to soft bounces. For example, if someone has a full mailbox and we keep sending emails that result in 3 soft bounces, they will eventually be marked as undeliverable. Wouldn't it be better to move such addresses to the Auto Suppression List for 4 months and then try sending again? This way, we avoid marking them as permanently undeliverable and potentially losing them forever.

I see nothing wrong with it, just from a cost/benefit point I don't think it's high prio. If you have reputation concerns, you can trade the effort against the benefit of a "tighter list". But say your delivery rates are anyway 99.% , I just would not bother too much. I do agree that you also probably won't lose a lot of high value addresses either. You know your scenario best.

Let the platform and the deliverability team do it's thing.
All bounces are transitory.  Yes, even the hard bounces.  The only true delivery conclusion is the status in All Subscribers.
SF Support can modify the bounce thresholds/timing for your BU, but (in my opinion) it's just a waste of time unless you have legal requirements to send paper if electronic means aren't viable and a robust upstream method of flagging bad email addresses.

I understand that a hard bounce can become active again, but I believe this is a rare occurrence in my case. Therefore, I plan to implement an automation that will overwrite the Auto Suppression List every 24 hours with data from the last 120 days. This allows me to dynamically manage problematic addresses while balancing efficiency in my sends and accommodating potential address corrections.
